# Cypress - Is It Possible to Intercept Properties Assigned to an Object for Assertion?

Tags: typescript, cypress

I have an event listener like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Button</button>
    <script>
        const FindThisProp = {}
        const button = document.querySelector('button');
        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            FindThisProp.prop = 'Found'
            return FindThisProp
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I call the object in the console, it returns an empty object. However, when I click on the button, the console returns the property 'Found'. Is it possible to add a Cypress test that can check whether an object has a specific key-value pair or just a particular value?

Answer (score 2):

Cypress can only see what's in the DOM, but the script creates a private scope where `FindThisProp` is created.

To access it from the test you would need to expose the object so that Cypress can access it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Button</button>
    <script>
        const FindThisProp = {}

        // expose here for testing, but only if Cypress is loaded
        if (window.Cypress) {
          window.FindThisProp = FindThisProp 
        }

        const button = document.querySelector('button');
        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            FindThisProp.prop = 'Found'
            return FindThisProp
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the test, get you object as "subject" and assert it's property

```js
cy.get('button').click()

cy.window()
  .its('FindThisProp')  // object is now exposed on window
  .its('prop')          // property of object
  .should('eq', 'Found')
```

To make it interesting, put a delay in the button click

```js
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    FindThisProp.prop = 'Found'
  }, 1000)
})
```

You should now see Cypress retry the `should()` assertion for one second before passing.

---

You can also put a reference to the object on a DOM element such as `<button>` if that seems more appropriate

```js
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  FindThisProp.prop = 'Found'
  if (window.Cypress) {
    button.FindThisProp = FindThisProp
  }
})
```

```js
cy.get('button').click()

cy.get('button')
  .its('0.FindThisProp')   // NOTE "0" prefix because subject is jQuery
  .its('prop')         
  .should('eq', 'Found')
```